# Changing whitespace color in Stani Python Editor

Tags: python, ide

I figured out how to edit the looks of SPE colors. Everything works except when I try change the whitespace color: whitespace remains white. Below is a code snippet showing value input for the whitespace background. How can I change the whitespace color?

```
# Global default styles for all languages
            self.StyleSetSpec(wx_stc.STC_STYLE_DEFAULT,     "face:%(mono)s,size:%(size)d" % self.faces)
            self.StyleSetSpec(wx_stc.STC_STYLE_LINENUMBER,  "back:#C0C0C0,face:%(mono)s,size:%(size)d" % self.faces)
            self.StyleSetSpec(wx_stc.STC_STYLE_CONTROLCHAR, "face:%(mono)s" % self.faces)
            self.StyleSetSpec(wx_stc.STC_STYLE_BRACELIGHT,  "fore:#FFFFFF,back:#0000FF,bold")
            self.StyleSetSpec(wx_stc.STC_STYLE_BRACEBAD,    "fore:#000000,back:#FF0000,bold")

            # Python styles
            # White space
            self.StyleSetSpec(wx_stc.STC_P_DEFAULT, "face:%(mono)s, back:#3366CC, size:%(size)d" % self.faces)
            # Comment
            self.StyleSetSpec(wx_stc.STC_P_COMMENTLINE, "face:%(mono)s,fore:#330099,back:#C0C0C0,italic,size:%(size)d" % self.faces)
            # Number
            self.StyleSetSpec(wx_stc.STC_P_NUMBER, "face:%(mono)s,fore:#00CC00,size:%(size)d" % self.faces)
            # String
            self.StyleSetSpec(wx_stc.STC_P_STRING, "face:%(mono)s,fore:#3399FF,size:%(size)d" % self.faces)
            # Single quoted string
            self.StyleSetSpec(wx_stc.STC_P_CHARACTER, "face:%(mono)s,fore:#7F007F,size:%(size)d" % self.faces)
            # Keyword
            self.StyleSetSpec(wx_stc.STC_P_WORD, "face:%(mono)s,fore:#339900,bold,size:%(size)d" % self.faces)
            # Triple quotes
            self.StyleSetSpec(wx_stc.STC_P_TRIPLE, "face:%(mono)s,fore:#FF3300,size:%(size)d" % self.faces)
            # Triple double quotes
            self.StyleSetSpec(wx_stc.STC_P_TRIPLEDOUBLE, "face:%(mono)s,fore:#7F0000,size:%(size)d" % self.faces)
            # Class name definition
            self.StyleSetSpec(wx_stc.STC_P_CLASSNAME, "face:%(mono)s,fore:#0000FF,bold,underline,size:%(size)d" % self.faces)
            # Function or method name definition
            self.StyleSetSpec(wx_stc.STC_P_DEFNAME, "face:%(mono)s,fore:#0066CC,bold,size:%(size)d" % self.faces)
            # Operators
            self.StyleSetSpec(wx_stc.STC_P_OPERATOR, "face:%(mono)s,bold,size:%(size)d" % self.faces)
            # Identifiers
            self.StyleSetSpec(wx_stc.STC_P_IDENTIFIER, "")
            # Comment-blocks
            self.StyleSetSpec(wx_stc.STC_P_COMMENTBLOCK, "face:%(mono)s,fore:#003300,back:#C0C0C0,italic,size:%(size)d" % self.faces)
            # End of line where string is not closed
            self.StyleSetSpec(wx_stc.STC_P_STRINGEOL, "face:%(mono)s,fore:#000000,face:%(mono)s,back:#E0C0E0,eol,size:%(size)d" % self.faces)
```

Comment: I am trying to find out how to change the background color of the editor

Comment: I've posted my comment as an answer to demonstrate the code fragment. It might be not a good idea to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment: It might be easier to read the configuration if you separate the data and the code:

```
settings = [
 "STYLE_DEFAULT", "face:%(mono)s,size:%(size)d",
 "STYLE_LINENUMBER",  "back:#C0C0C0,face:%(mono)s,size:%(size)d",
 ...
 "P_COMMENTBLOCK", "face:%(mono)s,fore:#003300,back:#C0C0C0,italic,size:%(size)d",
 "P_STRINGEOL", "face:%(mono)s,fore:#000000,face:%(mono)s,back:#E0C0E0,eol,size:%(size)d",
]

for name, value in zip(*[iter(settings)]*2):
    self.StyleSetSpec(getattr(wx_stc, "STC_"+name), value % self.faces)
```